# Uneven text in Latex, although I used the package ragged2e

Tags: latex

Here is the latex code:

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{article}
    \date{}
    
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{babel,etoolbox, lineno}
    
    \usepackage[natbib=true,style=ext-numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{name.bib}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
    \setstretch{1.5}
    
    \usepackage{geometry}
    
    \setlength{\parindent}{4em}
    
    
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    
    \begin{document}
    
  \par The value of "a" is the number of times the word occurs in the analysis text. The value of "b" is the number of times the word occurs in the reference text. The value of "c" is the total number of words in the analysis text. The value of "d" is the total number of words in the reference text.\par

Given this contingency table, WordHoard calculates the log-likelihood ratio statistic G2 to assess the size and significance of the difference of a word's frequency of use in the two texts. The log-likelihood ratio measures the discrepancy of the the observed word frequencies from the values which we would expect to see if the word frequencies (by percentage) were the same in the two texts. The larger the discrepancy, the larger the value of G2, and the more statistically significant the difference between the word frequencies in the texts. Simply put, the log-likelihood value tells us how much more likely it is that the frequencies are different than that they are the same.\par
When you compute many log-likelihood ratio values some will appear significant by chance alone. For example, if we compute one thousand log-likelihood values, we can expect about ten of them to exceed the breakpoint value of 6.63 by chance. This may lead us to accept a frequency difference as significant when it is really just a chance fluctuation.\par

One way to deal with this problem is to "up the ante" by adjusting the breakpoint values for the number of comparisons. WordHoard allows this as an option. The method used by WordHoard is called the Sidak correction. It is very conservative, particularly as the total number of comparisons increases.\par

As an example, let's see how comparing word form frequencies reveals some properties of Shakespeare's play "Othello, the Moor of Venice." The comparison we select will highlight lemmata that are disproportionately common or rare in Othello with respect to Shakespeare's tragedies as a whole. To compare the lemmata counts, select "Compare Many Word Forms" from the Analysis menu. WordHoard displays the following dialog.
    
    \end{document}
```

The outputted text is completely uneven, every line ends somewhere else, looks completely unformatted. I put \par before each paragraph. What could be the issue?

Comment: The sole purpose of `ragged2e` is to get uneven text

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Ok, yes, when I remove the ragged2e, the text is  more evenly aligned, but still on some line the text goes over margins. Looks very messy still. How can I assure that on no line the text goes beyond certain limit?

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre] that reproduces these overfull lines. Probably latex has trouble hyphenating some words, but how to fix will depend on why the hyphenation does not work

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Here I added reproducible example.

Comment: I don't get any overfull lines with your example. However I can imagine that custom words like `WordHoard` might pose a problem. You can help latex by giving possible break points: `Word\-Hoard`

Answer (score 1):

The `ragged2e` package's purpose is to have a ragged edge (vs block). If you don't want uneven line endings, don't use that package.

When I remove `\usepackage{ragged2e}` from your code, I get one line that's too long. It doesn't get hyphenated cause LaTeX doesn't know which language your text is in. Use the babel package for hyphenation, e.g., add `\usepackage[american]{babel}` in the packages list. With babel and without ragged2e I get block mode with all lines equally long.